# Hexstring to img conversion

Tags: python, image-processing, arduino, hex, image-conversion

I'm using an arduino board to take a picture and it returns a HEX string. I've tried numpy, openCV, binascii and others but i'm not able to convert and save this image in RGB like a picture.

I get an "corrupted image" I can't open on my device but if a throw it in [RAW Pixels](https://rawpixels.net/) I can see the image how it should be.

The original size of the picture (seted on arduino board is QVGA 320x240).

The HEX string is [HERE](https://pastebin.com/MumwRUZQ).
| EDIT: alternative HEX [HERE](https://justpaste.it/cp0d9).

And the result (by rawpixels) is [this](https://i.imgur.com/qjX87yG.png), revealing the data to represent a 320x240 image encoded using RGB565.

This is my actual code that saves a "corrupted file" but opens in rawpixels.net

```
with open('img.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

data = bytes.fromhex(data[2:])

with open('image.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: What format did you tell Raw Pixels the HEX string was?  You'll need to convert that to PNG format in order to save it as a .png file.

Comment: If you have already tried to do this conversion, post the code you tried to do it with, and someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Your pastebin is private, so inaccessible.

Comment: Looks like pastebin system identified it as a spam because the hex string is too long, posted it again here https://justpaste.it/cp0d9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the image in only a few lines of code using [opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

with open("hex.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    buff = bytes.fromhex(data)

# Convert to 3 channel uint8 numpy array representing the BGR image
img = cv2.cvtColor(
    np.frombuffer(buff, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(240, 320, 2), cv2.COLOR_BGR5652BGR
)
# Save the image to a png file
cv2.imwrite("image.png", img)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't just save a byte array as a png image, there are header information which are missing from the file. To be honest I'm not too familiar with the PNG format details, but I know you can easily convert the hex values to RGB by doing something like:

```
import numpy as np

with open("hex.txt",'r') as f:
    hex_str = f.read().strip()
    rgb = np.array([int(hex_str[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(hex_str),2)])
```

however running this code on the hex file you provided results in an array of length 153600 which is not the expected 320*240*3(230400) elements, so for the rest of the answer I define my own HEX string:

> 0000FF00FF000000FF00FF0000FF00FF000000FF00FF00000000FF00FF000000FF00FF0000FF00FF000000FF00FF0000

This should create a 4x4 Bayer filter.
Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h=4
w=4

with open("hex.txt",'r') as f:
    hex_str = f.read().strip()
    rgb = np.array([int(hex_str[i:i+2],16) for i in range(0,len(hex_str),2)]).reshape(h,w,3)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(rgb)
plt.show()
```

if you want to save the result, you can use plt.imsave() to generate properly formatted PNGs.
Edit:
Here is the image output generated by the code above:
[Bayer filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfBCj.png)

Comment: Not my down-vote, but I don't see how this could be correct because your code doesn't appear to address the RGB565 packing.

Comment: OP never mentioned RGB565 and my code is based on the conventional 24bit RGB, not 16 bit. Shouldn't be difficult to modify it to work with 565 but there is already an answer using opencv to do the conversion. This probably explains the mismatch between the expected size and the array size after conversion.

Comment: RGB565 is mentioned as last word in 5th paragraph.

Comment: granted, that's from an edit after initially posting the question, but it's crucial to decoding the data, so anyone not mentioning this fact can't possibly have solved the question.

Comment: yes, the question was edited after this answer was posted. I will try to update the solution once I have more time.

Comment: why bother? there's already an answer that solves the problem. SO is not an exam where you are supposed to copy the answers from your neighbor to get points.